# Create VM from raw file in ProxMox

Tags: linux, backup, virtual-machines, proxmox

I created a snapshot of a VM in ProxMox and generated a raw file of a VM.
That ProxMox of mine is runnning into problems and i need to create a VM in another ProxMox using that raw file...

The raw file is already in a storage of the ProxMox i need to create the VM, but i just can't create a VM using that RAW file...

I tried creating a new VM with a RAW format disk image and then just copying my raw file into that one ProxMox created, and overwriting it like i saw in a post on ProxMox.com, but it did'nt work... On the console it says "Failed to find boot device"

How do i do that?

Comment: is it a windows vm?

Comment: No... It's a Linux Distro ( CentOS )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. vzdump ( backup ) the vm
2. do a snapshot

Then just go to the new proxmox and create a new vm using that snapshot ( just move the .raw file using scp ) and restore the backup